# How to connect to Internet via wired USB ADSL modem in Ubuntu LiveUSB edition?

Tags: networking, usb, network-manager, modem

I have Alcatel Thomson SpeedTouch 330  USB model modem.I can Ubuntu Desktop 64 liveUSB flawlessly but I don't know how to set up my Internet connection? I tried Network manager and entered my ISP, username and password but it didn't work. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score -1):

In my experience no way to use NetworkManager, you can follow the adverts [in this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsbAdslModem/SpeedTouch). For me Method 1 worked, impossible to follow Method 2 because some packets are not available for the 12.04 version.I don't know if you can use it on a live environment, perhaps if you use a usb live with persistent mode